# How do you view battery usage on Android Pie?

Tags: battery, battery-life, 9.0-pie

In old Android versions, I would commonly go to view my battery percentage in the options to make sure that none of the apps running in the background were burning out the battery. In Android Pie, however, this is gone from the battery screen in settings. It used to be at the bottom of the settings screen, but it is no longer there.

Has this moved somewhere else in Android Pie? I can't find it.

Comment: Follow this. https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/unlock-developer-options-your-pixel-android-9-0-pie-0183349/

Comment: Then this: https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/get-oreos-battery-menu-back-android-pie-0183346/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question because I had a hard time tracking it down on the internet before finding it myself.

A lot of sites will recommend using the developer settings to enable v8 battery monitoring. This is unnecessary though. All you have to do is tap on the three dots in the top right corner to access the battery usage. You can also just search for "battery usage" in the top search bar for the android settings.

Hopefully, the existence of this post eases some people's android woes... or perhaps I'm just very simple for not having been able to figure this out sooner. Either way, if your sitting and reading this post, I hope your day is going well! =)

P.S. If your standing and reading this post and wondering if my well-wishing applies to you, it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Android's advanced battery stats are actually still present in Pie; you just have to know where to look to find 'em.

First, go to the main Battery page of the system settings, just like normal. See the three-dot overflow menu icon in the upper-right corner? Tap it.

source : https://www.computerworld.com/article/3305756/android/android-9-pie-battery-stats.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

[3C Battery Monitor on GooglePlay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ccc71.bmw&hl=en_US)

In my experience, it's pretty good on battery monitoring.